# Cannot run samba interface after installing 13.04

Tags: 13.04, samba

I cannot get the samba interface to run after installing 13.04. I installed samba through the software center on one machine, and through terminal `sudo apt-get install samba system-config-samba cifs-utils` on another with the same result.

The problem is the same with both machines - typing "samba" in dash gives no result. (Nothing shows up).

Comment: I'm going to try it, and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to run Samba in Ubuntu 13.04, you have to install it.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install samba samba-common
```

To complete the installation from terminal, then click **[here](http://www.unixmen.com/howto-install-and-configure-samba-share-in-ubuntu/)** for complete instruction.

I just got a machine up and running, installed Ubuntu 13.04 on it, and followed the instruction in the above link, and it worked.  See below:

[image]

Once I clicked on the Samba icon it opened the window below

[image]

Comment: Er, if you read my note you will see I did both actions suggested by you. The problem occurs after the apparently successful install.

Comment: Just click on the link in the answer, and it will take through the steps needed.

Comment: Mitch, I have done all of that. I have successfully installed samba. My problem is that it does not launch.

Comment: I don't get the samba icon. Never faced this problem in the earlier releases.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix the problem. It was happening because gksu is not installed in 13.04 by default, and dash presumably tries to run gksu system-config-samba, and does not find gksu.

To install gksu, open terminal and run
sudo apt-get install gksu

Then type :
gksu-properties

In the dialogue that follows set authentication mode to "sudo" and grab mode to "enable".

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem
even after installing "system-config-samba" samba app didn't show up.
Check this answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/303818/samba-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-13-04/330597#330597) it solved my problem.