# Cannot see Samba configuration tool in the Dash in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, samba, unity-dash

After a fresh installation of ubuntu 14.04 (my previous installation has seen to be broken somewhere reading .wmv file with VLC), I've installed Samba GUI tool from the software center.

It briefly appears in the launchpad then disappears. From this time I cannot the see in in the dash.

I've found this in askUbuntu [Cannot run samba interface after installing 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289574/cannot-run-samba-interface-after-installing-13-04)

but the command sudo apt-get install samba samba-common gives me nothing to install.

```
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
samba est déjà la plus récente version disponible.
samba passé en « installé manuellement ».
samba-common est déjà la plus récente version disponible.
Les paquets suivants ont été installés automatiquement et ne sont plus nécessaires :
  kde-l10n-engb kde-l10n-fr
Veuillez utiliser « apt-get autoremove » pour les supprimer.
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 8 non mis à jour.
```

The following guide [Install and Configure Samba share in Ubuntu 13.10 ‘Saucy Salamander’ , 13.04| Howto](http://www.unixmen.com/howto-install-and-configure-samba-share-in-ubuntu/) has no result either.

Any idea ?

Laurent06000

Comment: See my comment in http://askubuntu.com/questions/580356/ubuntu-14-04-samba-server-not-visible-anymore-from-windows-8-1-pc

Comment: Can you do an `apt-get upgrade` first?  Then `apt-get purge samba` and `apt-get autoremove`, then reboot and then try again?

Comment: I did that, rebooted and tried to re-install Samba but I still cannot see Samba in the Dash. During its installation, it appears in the launcher then disappear.

Comment: what happens if you type `system-config-samba` in the dash?

Comment: Nothing concerning Samba appear in the Dash (only System monitoring, System parameter, System testing, System logs). testparm gives me  : testparm
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[printers]"
Processing section "[print$]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

Comment: The GUI is apparently not included in the samba package... (facepalm) Answer coming up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the GUI for Samba, run:

```
sudo apt-get install system-config-samba
```

then go to the dash and type `system-config-samba` and that should be the only icon left.  Click that one!

Sorry for the back-and forth. I should have done the `apt-cache search samba GUI` as the first thing!

Comment: the commands you asked me to do : laurent06000@PC-DE-LDP:~$ sudo apt-get install system-config-samba
[sudo] password for laurent06000: 
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
system-config-samba est déjà la plus récente version disponible.
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 19 non mis à jour. NOTHING appears in the Dash when I type system-config-samba.
laurent06000@PC-DE-LDP:~$ apt-cache search samba GUI
laurent06000@PC-DE-LDP:~$

Comment: after a n'th re-install from scratch of Ubuntu Including a formatting of the of the / disk but not the /home disk (located on a separate disk) I'm still unable to see the system-config-samba in the Dash even if I DO see both Samba and Server of Files SMB/CIFS marked as installed in the Ubuntu sofwtare center. Could it be a file somewhere in my home directory that keeps this problem occuring ?

Comment: And from a terminal? Any output there when you type `gksudo system-config-samba`?

Comment: You've got it !!! It finally opened the Samba GUI and I had the option to keep it in the launcher.

Many thanks Fabby !!!

Comment: Whew!  ;-)  Comment ça se dit en Français? (Ouf?)

Comment: Oui :) tout à fait

Answer (score -1):

It seems that at some update someone enabled a firewall in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. By typing the command "sudo ufw allow samba" samba all sprang into life. I could see my samba shares from the machine which is running ubuntu and see other computers / phones in my house. 
I have been using samba for many years and thought I knew all the gotchas (of which there are very many) but all the problems I had before were not to do with a firewall as I knew I didn't have one.
If the introduction of the firewall with no indication to users to allow samba is indeed the cause of the "broken samba" fiasco with ubuntu it must have cost millions in unnecessary and frustrating work. Re-installing samba is the last resort and rarely works.